# How does lockless incrementing work in LDD3's "shortprint"?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, locking, linux-device-driver

I am having a hard time understanding how `shortp_incr_bp()` works. How is it able to atomically increment without the need for a spinlock or semaphore? (I don't really understand the provided comments.) What could happen if `barrier()` wasn't there? How does the optimization cause incorrect values? What is one way this optimization can go wrong?

```
/*
 * Input is managed through a simple circular buffer which, among other things,
 * is allowed to overrun if the reader isn't fast enough.  That makes life simple
 * on the "read" interrupt side, where we don't want to block.
 */
static unsigned long shortp_in_buffer = 0;
static unsigned long volatile shortp_in_head;
static volatile unsigned long shortp_in_tail;

/*
 * Atomically increment an index into "shortp_in_buffer"
 *
 * This function has been carefully written to wrap a pointer into the circular 
 * buffer without ever exposing an incorrect value. The "barrier" call is there 
 * to block compiler optimizations across the other two lines of the function. 
 * Without the barrier, the compiler might decide to optimize out the "new" 
 * variable and assign directly to "*index". That optimization could expose an 
 * incorrect value of the index for a brief period in the case where it wraps. 
 * By taking care to prevent in inconsistent value from ever being visible to 
 * other threads, we can manipulate the circular buffer pointers safely without 
 * locks.
 */
static inline void shortp_incr_bp(volatile unsigned long *index, int delta)
{
    unsigned long new = *index + delta;
    barrier();  /* Don't optimize these two together */
    *index = (new >= (shortp_in_buffer + PAGE_SIZE)) ? shortp_in_buffer : new;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's assuming that you have a single writer, and that the point is to do atomic updates with respect to the readers only ("without ever exposing an incorrect value"). It's not designed to allow multiple writers to atomically increment the same value at the same time.

Comment: As far as I understand this, it’s a simple way to do `READ_ONCE()` on some architectures (on the rest it might not work). Be careful in *consistency* vs. *serialization*.

Comment: "What could happen if barrier() wasn't there?" - Without the barrier, the compiler may decide to optimize out `new` variable and write intermediate result directly to the `index`, thus exposing incorrect value of `index` to the reader. Oh, wait, this is exactly written in the comments. [Sarcasm off] So, what is exactly unclear in the comments?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I mean to say "why would this optimization be a problem"? How would the optimization leave an incorrect value? What is one way this can go wrong (ASM wise)?

Comment: " How would the optimization leave an incorrect value? What is one way this can go wrong (ASM wise)?" - So, this is a real question. Add it to the question post.

Comment: @nanoman, between conditional and its branch may have passed some time when `*index` would be different (imagine no `new` variable in the code).